# Nginx routing (rewrite)

Tags: php, .htaccess, nginx

I am switching from Apache (htaccess) to Nginx and I can't figure out how to get rewrite to work.

Each of these folders have an `.htaccess` and an `index.php`:

```
test1/
   - .htaccess
   - index.php
test2/
   - .htaccess
   - index.php
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?rt=$1 [L,QSA]
```

index.php

```
switch ($_GET['rt']) {
  default:
    echo 'default page';
    break;

  case 'page2':
    echo 'page2';
    break;
}
```

If the user goes to the url `example.com/test1` it shows "default page" (actual URL would be `example.com/test1/index.php`).

Or if they go to `example.com/test2/page2` (actual URL would be `example.com/test2/index.php?rt=page2`) and the page would display "page2".

Nginx block I thought would work:

```
location /test1 {
    try_files $uri $uri/ index.php?rt=$uri;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following code in your Nginx block:

```
  location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
  }

  location @rewrite {
      rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?rt=$1 last;
  }
```

This will rewrite the path like: "domain.com/test" to domein.com/index.php?rt=test.

With another part like "domain.com/test/test2" to domein.com/index.php?rt=test/test

Hope it helps.

More about Nginx rewrite here: https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/

Comment: Not quite what I'm looking to do. If the user goes to `example.com/test1/page2` it'll be the same as going to `example.com/test1/index.php?rt=page2`

Comment: Aha I see. 

In that case just putting:

rewrite ^/test1/(.*)$ /index.php?rt=$1 last;

In the location block of test1 will work too.

Comment: Doesn't work. `rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?rt=$1 last;` keeps going back to the index of `example.com` so I tried `rewrite ^/(.*)$ /test1/index.php?rt=$1 last;` but that just goes to `example.com/test1/`

Comment: Try setting /test1 in the rewrite: "^/test1/(*.)$" that sould tell nginx to trigger the rule on example.com/test1

Comment: `rewrite ^/test1/(.*)$ /test1/index.php?rt=$1 last;` works! Thanks

Comment: That's because your virtually change the path. In your html you have to set the path from the root like /css/style.css. The beginning slash is important.